# Angular5: Validator.pattern not working with Input

Tags: regex, typescript, validation, input, angular5

I am not sure what Im doing wrong but I have tried several different possibilities and none of them seem to work, here is my code, hopefully someone can share some insight:

HTML:

```
   <div *ngIf="formGroup.get(value)?.error(validation.pattern)">
      Display text if input doesnt match regex
    </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
  @Input()
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    formControlName: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(this.pattern))
  });

  @Input()
  formControlName = 'default';
```

NOTE: `this.pattern`is in the correct Regex format

Comment: Show the `this.pattern` value.

Comment: '^([A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{3})([A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{5})([\\dX])(([A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d])([A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d])([A-HJ-NPR-Z\\d]{6}))$'

Comment: Ok,, so the problem is not with the pattern.